# CSS & jQuery - transform text to "capitalize" - when got with .val() get's lowercase

Tags: jquery, css, capitalize

As you can see in example, i've putted all lowercase text and it shows uppercase, but when i use `.val()` in jQuery to get value, i get lowercase.. But if you type in uppercase it will be uppercase..

```js
$(function(){
  console.log($('#test_capitalize').val());
  $('#re-test').on('click', function(){ 
    console.log($('#test_capitalize').val());
  });
});
```

```css
#test_capitalize {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="test_capitalize" value="some small text" />

<button id="re-test">Get value</button>
```

Is it a bug or it should behave like this... ?

Comment: i believe this is the expected behavior

Comment: So it just tricks your eyes :D

Comment: `Is it a bug or it should behave like this... ?` YES, that is the expected behaviour.

Comment: You can check your `HTML` code in the console and see that the value of the input has not changed to capitalize. It's still the same.

Comment: the value don't change, only the css changes the appearance

Comment: Got it, thank you all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I understand your question. 
The value of the input is case sensitive, therefore if you type lowercase the `value` of the input will be lowercase, same case for uppercase.

You are seeing capitalized words in the input because you're applying a `text-transform: capitalize;` to it via css. This is used to pretty-print the text, but is for display only, it won't alter the actual value of the input field. That's why you are seeing the non-capitalized value in the console.